# Issue with form Submit - information to database and redirect to thank you page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Issue with form Submit - information need to be sent to database and the need to redirect to thank you page

Here is the code and fiddle link as well. Thanks.

I am trying to redirect to - Thank You page

Instead I am redirected to - "action"- URL

With the existing code, there is no issue of sending information to database. It works fine, just that it is not redirecting me to the Thank you page.

HTML:

```
 <form name="MailingList" method="post" Id="formId" action="URL" onsubmit="return validate_form(this);">
 <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="100" size="28">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" width="260px">
</form>

var frmvalidator = new Validator("MailingList");

frmvalidator.addValidation("Email", "maxlen=50");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email", "req");
frmvalidator.addValidation("Email", "email");

<script>
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('#subscribe').click(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL',
        data: 'emailaddress=' + jQuery('input[name="emailaddress"]').val(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (jQuery(data).find('.subscribe_valid').length) {
                location.href = 'Thank you page';
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error handling here');
        }
    });
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: The validator above is outside script tags and will never work. Please see my answer to your original code

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites**

1. form and script needs to live at the same origin as the Ajax target - if not, no need to read any further - for example you can never test teabeyond from jsfiddle.
2. jQuery has to be loaded before the script
3. Validation has to be inside the jQuery load event handler

Then you need to
 cancel the form submission with

```
....submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Here is the code attempting to fix the original question. I would expect a serialised form rather than a context in the ajax

***NOTE*** jsFiddle CANNOT Ajax to another site than jsFiddle itself so the code will NOT work at jsFiddle

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8zeL4mn1/)

```
function validate_form(theForm) {
    if (theForm.emailaddress.value=="") {
        alert("Please enter email");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$(function () {
  $('#formId').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the form
    if (validate_form(this)) {
      // the form's action MUST point to a page on the same origin as the form
      $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(),
        function () {
          window.location.replace("https://www.othersite.com/Articles.asp?ID=252"); 
      });
    }
  });
});
```

instead of `$(this).serialize(),` you can have

```
{"emailaddress2",this.emailaddress2.value}
```

Comment: It is the main error so it should work unless there are other js errors. Look in the console

Comment: <script src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> - form validation script

Comment: First things first. Get the submission to work. I will let you get on with it. Perhaps get someone to to it for you?

Answer (score -2):

You `replace` isn't going to do anything, since you aren't providing it with a second parameter. The replace method is like this:

```
String.replace('texttolookfor', 'replacementtext');
```

[String replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

If you want to redirect, then you need to give the `replace` method the url of where you want to go:

```
window.location.replace("https://www.teabeyond.com/Articles.asp?ID=252", "http://www.teabeyond.com/MailingList_subscribe.asp");
```

You might want to use the console to verify your address and what not.

Also, per @mplungjan, you need to prevent the default submit action.

Comment: Location.replace is not String.replace